# Having trouble working with UserManager<IdentityUser>

Tags: c#

Am trying to create login/registration functionality, I am using user manager but am having trouble figuring it out when my code hits the section where user manager is used I get this error `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'. at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,`, I have no idea what this means or implies, Ive tried looking at some resources but they've only amplified my confusion, if anyone can help or direct me I would be greatfull.

```
//Register method    
    public async Task<Authentication_result> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string Username)
            {
                var exists = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
                
    
                if (exists != null)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "User with this email already exists" }
                    };
                }
    
                var newPerson = new IdentityUser
                {
                    Email = email,
                    UserName = Username
    
                };
    
    
                var Creation = await _manager.CreateAsync(newPerson, password);
      
                if (!Creation.Succeeded)
                {
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Errors = new[] { "Invalid user!" }
                    };
                }
    
                return Generate_Authentication_Result(newPerson);
            }
    


 //Login method
              public async Task<Authentication_result> LoginAsync(string email, string Password)
        {


            var exists = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);


            if (exists == null)
            {
                return new Authentication_result
                {
                    Errors = new[] { "User does not exists" }
                };
            }

            var pass_validation = await _manager.CheckPasswordAsync(exists, Password);

            if (!pass_validation)
            {
                return new Authentication_result
                {
                    Errors = new[] { "f78wrvep034rf wrong" }
                };
            }

            return Generate_Authentication_Result(exists);
        }
//User module

 public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PreferredNet { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Number { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Inactive { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Active { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Max_Return { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time {get;set;}
    }
//DbSet
 public class DataContext:IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options):base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Users> users { get; set; }
        
       
    }
```

Comment: It is looking for a table named `AspNetUsers` in your SQL database, which it cannot find.  Have you created all the back-end objects in your sql server required to use asp.net identity?

Comment: Probably not, am a little new to this depth of working with tables, what I have is a couple of DbSets one of which is "Users" based on my models, I'll edit the question I posted to include the class that inherits from IdentityDataContext as well as my module class, the intel in your comment has been helpful, really appreciate,at least I now know whats going on.

Comment: If you are using the "Code First", you will need to run `add-migration` and `update-database` from the package manager console in order to update SQL.  If you are using "db first", you will need to manually create the sql objects yourself, or find a script to do it.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: So the migration was successful but the update gave me the error "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'Sub' does not exist in table 'users' " which again am not sure what to make of.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting that error specifically, but I can at least explain what the error means.The command is looking in the database table that it is trying to modify, for a column named `Sub`.  It is trying to remove this column, but it is throwing an error because the column does not exist.  This makes me think that your current database is out of sync with your `DbContext`.  If you don't have any data in the database you want to save, I'd recommend deleting the database, and running the `create-database`, and `update-database` commands to recreate it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you so so much this has been really helpful. So just one more thing, the creat-database command will create based on my Dbset right?

Comment: So I did as you advised and now all my problems have been solved, thank you once again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, so like I said you advise and input worked perfectly and I was wondering if you could help me understand something, I modified the dbo.AspnetUser table with some custom columns but when I tried to access those columns only the ones native to the table show up, why is this the case and how do I solve it?